# Replace/remove words in a string that exist in a separate list

Tags: scala, replace

I am looking for a better, cleaner method to scrub bad words from a long string.

I have a text file with hundreds of bad words and I am looping over each one - using it to create a regex pattern and replacing matches with asterisks.

```scala
import scala.io.Source

def removeBadWords(comment: String): String = {
  val bufferedBadWords = Source.fromFile("/Users/me/Desktop/badwords.txt")
  val badWords = bufferedBadWords.getLines.toList
  bufferedBadWords.close

  var newComment = comment
  for(badWord <- badWords) {
    newComment = badWord.r.replaceAllIn(newComment, "*" * badWord.length)
  }

  newComment
}

val sentence = "These are just a couple of [bad word] sentences. I want to [bad word] replace certain words with [bad word] asterisks - if [bad word] possible."
println(removeBadWords(sentence))

// Result: These are just a couple of **** sentences. I want to ******* replace certain words with ******* asterisks - if ******* possible.
```

Is there a more performant and more idiomatic way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it all in a single pass but you might not be able to have the replacement string match the length of the bad string.

```
def removeBadWords(comment :String) :String =
  io.Source
    .fromFile("badwords.txt")       //open file
    .getLines                       //without newline chars
    .mkString("\\b(", "|", ")\\b")  //regex with word boundaries
    .r                              //compile
    .replaceAllIn(comment, "****")  //return cleaned comment
```